# Odoo 16 Online - Calculated field - error on new record

Tags: odoo-16

I have a computed field that calculates the time duration between today, and when a person joined the company. It works, as long as the dependent field (x_studio_join_date) already contains something. Buf if it is empty, like when I create a new record, it fails with the following error.

Clearly the computed field is being called before the record has been initialized. The 'required' attribute has had no effect. I thought the conditional test (if record['x_studio_join_date'] != False:) would prevent the computation from accessing a still null field, but this doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dependencies: x_studio_join_date
Compute: 

for record in self:
   if record['x_studio_join_date'] != False:
      start_date = record.x_studio_join_date
      end_date = datetime.date.today()
      time_delta = end_date - start_date
      years, remainder_days = divmod(time_delta.days, 365.25)
      months, days = divmod(remainder_days, 30.44)
   if years > 0:
      txt = '{:}y {:}m {:}d'.format(int(years), int(months), int(days))
   elif months > 0:
      txt = '{:}m {:}d'.format(int(months), int(days))
   elif days > 0:
      txt = '{:}d'.format(int(days))
   else:
      txt = "n/a"
   record['x_studio_duration'] = txt
```

Returns the following

```
RPC_ERROR
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "......api.py", line 958, in get
cache_value = field_cache[record._ids[0]]
KeyError: <NewId 0x7ff30fa1a1a0>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "....fields.py", line 1158, in __get__
value = env.cache.get(record, self)
File "....api.py", line 965, in get
raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'hr.employee(<NewId 0x7ff30fa1a1a0>,).x_studio_duration'
```